# Where to set compression.type property in Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

I want to implement compression for Kafka messages. For that  `compression.type` must be set. In which property file it should be set?

Answer (score 3):

If you set `compression.type`  property in the configuration of the producer, then the messages will be compressed before sending them to the broker. If you set this property in the server configuration, then it specifies how the messages will be compressed in the broker. In the server side you can also specify `producer`, which means use the compression type set by the producer.

Answer (score 2):

you can add ProducerConfig  (https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#producerconfigs )

it support gzip, snappy, lz4

and Topic's Config also be set . ( https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#topicconfigs )

and,
consumer does not need to be set (auto detecting)

Comment: What will be the impact of compression? Whether processing will get faster?

Comment: @omi138 processing is actually will be slower because the CPU has to work harder in order to compress your message. But you can reduce the kafka disk usage and bypass some potential issues with kafka message limits.

Comment: @walv not necessarily slower. If operation is IO bound (e.g. reading/writing from disk) compression can make it faster.